# Is there a way to get the Spinner object that was changed in OnItemSelectedListener?

Tags: android, onitemselectedlistener

I have an array of spinners with the same OnItemSelectedListener but I need to know which spinner was selected (preferably where I can get the index of the array) so I can pass it on as the index of another array.

These are my spinners:

```
insulSpinners = new Spinner[6];
insulSpinners[0] = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.insulSpin1);
insulSpinners[1] = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.insulSpin2);
insulSpinners[2] = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.insulSpin3);
insulSpinners[3] = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.insulSpin4);
insulSpinners[4] = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.insulSpin5);
insulSpinners[5] = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.WireSpin);

awcSpinners = new Spinner[6];
awcSpinners[0] = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.awcSpin1);
awcSpinners[1] = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.awcSpin2);
awcSpinners[2] = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.awcSpin3);
awcSpinners[3] = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.awcSpin4);
awcSpinners[4] = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.awcSpin5);
awcSpinners[5] = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.awcSpin6);

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    insulSpinners[i].setOnItemSelectedListener(insuls);
    awcSpinners[i].setOnItemSelectedListener(awcs);
    }
```

I need the nth spinner of insulSpinners from the listener so I can apply a function to the nth spinner of awcSpinners. The text that is selected on the insulSpinner is used in the function. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OnItemSelectedListener has two methods.

```
onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
```

Both give you the used spinner as a reference `AdapterView<?> parent`.

You can add the index of each spinner as a tag and then you can check the tag. From the tag, you can infer the index of the spinner.

For example

```
int[] ids = {R.id.insulSpin1, R.id.insulSpin2, ...}
for (int idx = 0; idx < ids.length(); i++) {
  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(ids[idx])
  spinner.setTag(idx); // you may need to wrap it in an Integer object
  insulSpinners[idx] = spinner
}

// and then in your onItemSelected method callback
void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  int tag = (Integer) parent.getTag()
  Spinner selectedSpinner = insulSpinners[tag]
  // do something...
}
```

Comment: Do I need to give each of the insulSpinners a different adapter? They currently all have the same one. Easy change

Comment: I don't think so, but I don't know what you do in the adapter